# Build a document from a filtered query in FlutterFlow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I am new in flutterflow, I'm trying to make a document from a filtered query. I already have the collection for the new document and the collection to filter.

I tried to use the Code Copilot AI and it gave me a code that does not work, it shows an error in the "fromMap" of NominaRecord.fromMap(doc.data());

(The editor didnt let me to paste the entire code...)

Another solution may be to build an appstate list with one data of each filtered document. I also tried this but I couldn't do it...

Please help!!!!